# Appcelerator Titanium Push Notification for Android?

Tags: android, notifications, titanium, push, appcelerator

I am New to Titanium can anyone help me to understand the concept of push notification for Android in Appcelerator Titanium.i.e Sample code for creating Simple push Notification.
Thank u

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple push notification [example](https://github.com/donthorp/androidng/blob/master/assets/Resources/android-activity-notification.js). Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank U Zeeshan .This sample i have implemented(It's a normal notification).but i want to implement Push Notification with C2DM server in Appcelerator Titanium.please if u know post here.Thank u again